# How do Android apps like Facebook, Whatsapp have services in foreground without notification?

Tags: android, android-service

My app has a service which starts during boot, and it needs to keep running. However, when I close my app by swiping it on the "Recent apps" screen, the service stops. To get around this, I used startForeground with a notification, and now my service keeps running even when I kill the app. My query is : how do apps like Facebook, Whatsapp, etc operate? They have services which keep running even when we kill the app, but I don't see any notification in the notification bar saying "Facebook is running"  or "Whatsapp is running".

Comment: What version of Android are you trying this on?

Comment: Android version 4.4.2

Comment: Bear in mind that "a service which starts during boot, and it needs to keep running" is an anti-pattern. Few apps need this. Trying to do so without user awareness and control is unethical. The fact that Facebook and Whatsapps may be behaving unethically is no excuse for *you* to behave unethically.

Comment: I can confirm that my app needs this, and the user will also be informed of the same.

Comment: "I can confirm that my app needs this" -- you are welcome to your opinion. "the user will also be informed of the same" -- by means of having the `Notification` be in the status bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no officially supported way to keep a service running without a foreground notification (nor should there be). If there are any loopholes found to get around this, Google will surely (and has in the past) fix them, breaking any apps that are exploiting them.

I cannot say how exactly Facebook and Whatsapp work, but if you are asking how they notify the user of new messages in real-time, they are likely relying on [Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) for push notifications, which does not require a service or your application to be constantly running.

Comment: +1 Yes, you can simulate a constantly running application using GCM. This is the correct answer.

Comment: GCM is a bad idea and it's very unstable http://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/. You can fix that by manual pings to google servers. Regarding FB, Whatsapp they are maintaining a persistent TCP connection and pinging to their servers (for whatsapp you can see pings in logcat - FB I don't know how mqtt works.

Comment: @user2223032 "for whatsapp you can see pings in logcat " .How to implement such ping in android?

Comment: @user3705478 alarmmanager. check this for mqtt - https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android/blob/master/org.eclipse.paho.android.service/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/android/service/AlarmPingSender.java

Answer (score 2):

This bug was introduced in Android 4.4.1. Before this, swiping out didn't kill any service.
Here is the link to the problem
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/H-DSQ4-tiac

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a separate process for your service by defining a process for service in manifiest.xml file. Both your app and service runs on separate process. Your app get kills but you service keep running.

```
<service android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
         android:exported=["true" | "false"]
         android:icon="drawable resource"
         android:isolatedProcess=["true" | "false"]
         android:label="string resource"
         android:name="string"
         android:permission="string"
         android:process="string" >
    . . .
</service>
```

Comment: Fortunately, this does not work. Task managers, such as swiping the app of the recent-tasks list, will terminate both processes, particularly on 4.4.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot CommonsWare. This prevents me from trying to implement this idea. I guess I'll just go with the Notification.